# How do I read in a double in Java?

Tags: java, input, double

I am trying to get a decimal input from the keyboard, and it is just not working.  First I tried

```
double d = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                    "Please enter a number between 0 and 1:"));
```

and that obviously didn't work very well.

I am used to just parsing int's as they come in from the keyboard right into a variable, but I don't know what I am supposed to do for decimals! I need to be able to take a decimal like .9 straight from the keyboard and be able to have it in a variable I can do calculations with.

I know this is a basic question, but I need some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double d = new Double(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number between 0 and 1:"));
```

Comment: What is then? Double.parseDouble? Why is that any better?

Comment: `double d = new Double` creates a object of type `Double` and then immediately discards it in favor of the primitive `double`. `Double.parseDouble` avoids the two unnecessary steps in between.

Comment: I'm not Java bytcode expert, but it's possible the modern compilers will compile them to the same thing. At least in theory, such things are done in other languages.

Answer (score 8):

I would use the [Double](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) class rather than the Integer class

```
double d = Double.parseDouble((String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a number between 0 and 1:"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried substituting `Double` for `Integer` ?

So `Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a double:"));`
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Or `Double.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a double:"))`
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`Double.parseDouble(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29). Another option is [`Double.valueOf(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28double%29) and I prefer the later because it's more change tolerant (if the parameter is changed for something else than a `String`, you may not have to modify your code), even if it creates an unnecessary `Double` that you don't need in your example.